# Encoding characters in mozilla firefox

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, mozilla

I have a problem with my encoding in mozilla firefox, I tried in chrome and explorer, everything goes well. The problem is that : If I submit the form and login or password are invalide the charcaters are not encoding.
I added on the html :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Is that a problem in mozilla? Help me please. Exist a solution for this problem?

Comment: What you see duplicate? My problem is not with mysql but after a submit form

Comment: It's rather unclear what exactly the issue is here. The duplicate still provides many hints, even if you ignore the MySQL part. The duplicate is about UTF-8 *all the way through*, not just specifically to MySQL. See if [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) is more to your liking. If that didn't help, at least update your question with more specifics and try to check off all the points raised in these two articles/answers.

Comment: I found the solution : it must add 
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); to top at submit method